# JASidePanel : Need to maintain permanently a menu to the left

Tags: objective-c

I'm studying the JASidePanel stackController.

But I would like to know if there is a possibility to maintain permanently a menu to the left of the screen independently of the JASidePanel.

In order to do that, I have tried to insert the JASidePanelController as a subview of an other UIViewController like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // My part ---------------------
    UIViewController *rootViewController = [ [ UIViewController alloc ] init ];
    UIView *rootView = [ [ UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero ];
    rootView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth + UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [rootView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];

    rootViewController.view = rootView;
    // ---------------------

    JASidePanelController *sidePanelController =[[JASidePanelController alloc] init];
    sidePanelController.leftFixedWidth = 260;

    self.viewController = sidePanelController;
    self.viewController.shouldDelegateAutorotateToVisiblePanel = NO;

    self.viewController.leftPanel = [[JALeftViewController alloc] init];
    self.viewController.centerPanel = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[JACenterViewController alloc] init]];
    self.viewController.rightPanel = [[JARightViewController alloc] init];

    self.viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(61, 0, self.viewController.view.frame.size.width, self.viewController.view.frame.size.height );
    [ rootView addSubview:self.viewController.view ];

    // My part ---------------------
    self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
    // ---------------------
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

It works but I am not fully satisfied.

Indeed, when I swipes my finger  to the left, in order to show the right panel, the center panel don't move correctly to the left and covers my personal menu (in yellow).

As a result, the right panel is not visible totally and my menu (in yellow) is not visible.

Please, have a look to my illustrations to understand what I want to do.

Is anyone have a idea of how to do that?

Many thanks per advance!

[image] [image] [image]